# Have at least on checkbox in checkbox group visually(!) checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm looking for a way to have in a group of checkboxes at least on checkbox checked. 
The only things i could find was methods to validate IF at least one checkbox is checked, but you where always able to check/uncheck the last checkbox - is there a way to make sure, when the user clicks the checkboxes that at least one checkbox has to remain checked (and only if at least two checkboxes are checked one of both can be unchecked) ?

Thanks for your help!
Vin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes 'change' in value, so it's probably best to listen for that. Remember 'click' would only handle mouse clicks, so one could still change the val w/ enter or spacebar. For accessibility, i'd stick with `onchange.`

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p95fmjk/47/)

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p95fmjk/65/)

js

```
$(function () {
    $('.cbClassSegments').on('change', function (e) {
            
        !$(this).siblings(':checked').length &&
            $(this).prop('checked', true) &&
                e.preventDefault();

        // move assignment down and prevent default action 
        cbObjSegments[this.id] = this.checked;
        console.log(valuesTrueInObject(cbObjSegments));
 
    })
})
```

html

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Now theres one quest left: I like to store the values of the checkboxes in an object for further computations. The last checkbox is still clickable and the value gets changed in the object and it shouldn't.
See: http://jsfiddle.net/9p95fmjk/56/

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(event) {
    var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('input[name="name"]:checked').length;

    if(atLeastOneIsChecked<1){ 
           event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsb5tcg0/)

Comment: I don't think the checkboxes will be named the same. Wouldn't make sense.